# How to read multiple times from inpust stream?

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have InputStream as input (it's a big .zip) which contains several files like:

- xxx1.xml
- xxx2.xml
- xxx2_old.xml

First I need to determine a file I want to process (Lexicographic order) like:

```java
String getFileName(List<String> filenames){
        return filenames.stream()
                .filter(PREDICATE)
                .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }
}
```

Then I need to pass this .xml file as InputStream for further parsing.

It would be easy to operate on objects in memory, but I don't know how to approach this with InputStream. The solution should be memory efficient so I cannot just save everything.
Should I read it 2 times?

Comment: Create a ZipInutStream, scan for your file (a ZipEntry), and process it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on target.

DOM parser load all information into memory. SAX parser is a stream processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ZipFile` you only need to open the ZIP file once. `ZipFile` let's you get an input stream based on an entry.

```
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    ZipEntry entry = entry.nextElement();
    if (entry matches filter) {
        InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        // use inputStream as needed
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use `ZipInputStream`:

```
try (ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(...)) {
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry matches filter) {
            // use zipStream as needed, just don't close it!
        }
        zipStream.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

That remark about not closing the `ZipInputStream` is important; apart from the `close()` method the stream works just like a stream for a separate entry. Closing it will close the entire ZIP file though.
If needed, Apache Commons IO has [CloseShieldInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) that can be used to wrap the ZIP stream, so when the wrapper is closed the ZIP stream isn't.

Edit: the `ZipInputStream` solution indeed needs two loops, because the file to use depends on all other files. The `ZipFile` solution can still be used. Loop once to get the right file, then use `zipFile.getInputStream(getEntry(fileName))`, or if you store the entry instead of just its name, `zipFile.getInputStream(file)`.

Comment: In my solution, I use ZipInputStream very similarly. The issue is that I need to go through all entries to get a list of fileNames, and determine the right one. In the next step, I would need to create new ZipInputStream one more time from the same inputStream and go through it and pass the right entry to further processing.

Comment: @TakeItAll that max file name does mean a `ZipInputStream` isn't that useful. But how about a `ZipFile`? You can first loop using the `Enumeration` to determine the correct file name (old-style, not using a stream). Then use `getInputStream(getEntry(fileName))` to get the input stream. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I have InputStream on input so converting it to zipInputSteram is quite straightforward. Using ZipFile means I need to save inputstream as ZipFile, so it won't be memory friendly. Do I get it right?

Comment: `ZipFile` is, as the name suggests, a _file_. That doesn't necessarily mean it's not memory friendly, but you do have to save the contents of the input stream to disk first. That means you have to go through the input stream at least twice - once to store, once to find the entry (and then there's the time that `zipFile.getInputStream` needs).